# Cannot create contract "invalid identifier" second time loading

Tags: ethers.js, abi

I create a contract interface with ether.js, below the error is the onMount function. The "first time" the component is mounted, the contract is created without problem. The **second time**, and subsequent times, the line which is now setting the iface, throws an error saying that `"mint(string,bytes)"` does not exist - although, I am seeing it in the ABI (also added in this post at the bottom). I've also double and a hundred times over-checked that contractInfo does not change (it doesn't).

What could be happening?!

```
ror: invalid identifier "mint(string,bytes)" (argument="value", value="mint(string,bytes)", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (null:196:23)
    at Logger.throwError (null:205:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (null:208:21)
    at verifyIdentifier (null:1668:13)
    at FunctionFragment.fromObject (null:2093:17)
    at Fragment.fromObject (null:1856:37)
    at Fragment.from (null:1848:25)
    at null:2725:27
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at new Interface (null:2724:47)
    at loadFunctions (ContractInterface.svelte:38:14)
(
```

```
onMount(() => {
        const actualProvider = web3Provider.get();
        const jsonContract = await contracts.daolabs[readNetwork.get().alias][contractInfo.name]();
        console.log('ABI:', jsonContract.abi);
        const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(jsonContract.abi);
        console.log('Interface:', iface);
        contract = new ethers.Contract(contractInfo.address, iface, actualProvider.getSigner());
    })
```

```json
{
    "type": "function",
    "name": "mint(string,bytes)",
    "constant": false,
    "stateMutability": "payable",
    "payable": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "type": "bytes"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ]
}
```